# Thumb parameter of send_video function not working! Telegram bot Python

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

```
context.bot.send_video(chat_id=update.message.chat_id, video=vid, caption='the video', thumb= pic)
```

vid variable is the video file id and pic variable is the thumbnail photo file id

The bot is able to send the video correctly but it doesn't change the thumbnail as desired. The video even has the caption "the video"!

Is there something wrong with my code or with the thumb parameter?

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK Telegram tends to ignore the thumbnail if the video is small enough. In that case, TG just generates the thumb from the video. At least for the [`InputMedia*`](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#inputmediavideo) classes, this is in fact documented.

Answer (score 1):

If your video size is `<10-20MB` telegram will automatically generate thumb. But, above that you can specify the `thumb` from your local jpg image.
Remember that The thumbnail should be in `JPEG` format and less than `200 KB` in size. A thumbnail’s width and height should not exceed `320 px`.